# Change colour of checkboxes in Shiny `checkboxGroupInput`

Tags: shiny

In Shiny is it possible to change the colour of checkboxes from the default blue in the below example?

```
library("shiny")
server = function(input, output) {

  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$checkGroup })

}

ui = fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                     choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3),
                     selected = 1),


  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

)

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably here you may find the answer: https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/

The **shinythemes** package makes it easy to alter the overall appearance of your Shiny applications. For instance:

[image]

Also, I would recommend reading this post on styling the checkbox usig CSS: [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

> UPDATE: The below answer references the state of things before
>   widespread availability of CSS3. In modern browsers (including
>   Internet Explorer 9 and later) it is more straightforward to create
>   checkbox replacements with your preferred styling, without using
>   javascript.
>
> Here are some useful links:
>
> - [Easy CSS3 Checkboxes and Radio Buttons](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)
> - [Collection of checkbox styles from CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles)
> - [Creating Custom Form Checkboxes with Just CSS](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/)
> - [Easy CSS Checkbox Generator](http://csscheckbox.com/)
> - [Stuff You Can Do With The Checkbox Hack](http://Stuff%20You%20Can%20Do%20With%20The%20Checkbox%20Hack)
> - [Implementing Custom Checkboxes and Radio Buttons with CSS3](http://www.css3.com/implementing-custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-css3/)
> - [How to Style a Checkbox With CSS](http://How%20to%20Style%20a%20Checkbox%20With%20CSS)
>
> It is worth noting that the fundamental issue has not changed. You
>   still can't apply styles (borders, etc.) directly to the checkbox
>   element and have those styles affect the display of the HTML checkbox.
>   What has changed, however, is that it's now possible to hide the
>   actual checkbox and replace it with a styled element of your own,
>   using nothing but CSS. In particular, because CSS now has a widely
>   supported :checked selector, you can make your replacement correctly
>   reflect the checked status of the box.